# SQL Paging (Offset, Fetch) query is very slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't understand what is happening here. I am querying a single table as seen by my query below. I am only fetching the first 20 records yet the query is takes 24 seconds to complete.

Is there any way to speed up this paging query?

```
;WITH TempResult AS(
     SELECT distinct


       D.GLCompany
      ,D.GLAcct
      ,D.GLProdNum
      ,D.GLCostCenter         
      ,D.FCSCompany
      ,D.FCSAcct
      ,D.FCSCostCenter     
      ,D.JournalDetailId
      ,D.[EffDt]
      ,D.[JournalLineAmt]
      ,D.[JournalLineDesc]     
      ,D.[ManagedByCd]
      ,D.[LegalOwnerId]
      ,D.[JournalLineNum]
      ,D.[RoundedFlagBit]
      ,D.[CLPreValErrCd]
      ,D.[GLPreValErrCd]
      ,D.[SuspenseErrCd]
      ,D.GLProfitCenter
      ,D.GLTradingPartner
      ,D.GLInternalOrder
      ,D.GLSubAcct
      ,D.GLAcctActivity
      ,D.GLDataSrc
      ,D.GLId
      ,D.GLProdGrp 
      ,D.HeaderId   
     from MyDetail  D
 )


    SELECT *  FROM TempResult
 ORDER BY  TempResult.HeaderId
  OFFSET 0  ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
 OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

There is a non clustered index on headerid as seen below

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FCSAcctJournalDetail_idx] ON [dbo].[MyDetail]
(
    [FCSAcct] ASC,
    [FCSCompany] ASC,
    [JournalEntryEffDt] ASC,
    [DataDt] ASC,
    [HeaderId] ASC,
    [JournalDetailId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Comment: 1. `distinct` .2. [OFFSET](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Comment: Yea I took Distinct off and it went down to 9 seconds. Still its slow for just 20 records

Comment: Do you have an index on HeaderId? Do you really need the DISTINCT?

Comment: Is `MyDetail` a regular table or view?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda its a regular table.

Comment: And what are the indexes?

Comment: @Milney Yes there is a  nonclustered index on HeaderId along with a few other columns in that statement

Comment: The query you've posted doesn't need a cte.

Comment: Also, why the `recompile` hint?

Comment: That index isn't useful in that query.  You need to ORDER BY the leading columns in an index to avoid completely re-sorting the table to fetch the first 20 rows.

Comment: Technically, you DO NOT have an index on HeaderID. HeaderID is "included" in the index you've shared, but it's so far down the list that it is not going to mean much to sort by just "header_id". The columns listed in the index define the order of the index data. If sorting by HeaderID is required, I would add a NC index on just HeaderID alone. Imagine sorting an Excel file of people by Last_Name, First_Name and Birth_Date... then trying to find all the people with a birth date in June. The fact that birth_date is included in the sort, after names... wont help.

Comment: The sort by birth date helps when you have someone with the same name, but wont help at all for searching the data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an index on `HeaderId`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FCSAcctJournalDetail_HeaderId_idx] ON [dbo].[MyDetail]
(
    [HeaderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

As David Browne wrote in his comment - the index you currently have is irrelevant to this query.

If the `HeaderId` was the first column in the index it would be relevant, but since it's not the first (and not even close to being the first), it's simply irrelevant in the context of this query.